# how do I make a bigger array and copy over the info from the previous array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to use to store info from a text file into a array, but the project asks us to do so by making a temporary array and increasing its size as we read more files to accomadate for the new objects. How can I do this?

```
/**
 * reads a csv data file and returns an array of acquaintances
 * @param path File path of CSV file
 * @return Acquaintances from the file
 */
public static Acquaintance[] read (String path)  {
    //create an array of acquaintances 
    Acquaintance[] acqs = new Acquaintance[0];

    //open the file
    try {
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

        //read the file until the end
        String line;

        while( (line = file.readLine()) != null) {
            // parse the line just read
            String[] parts = line.split(",");

            //create an acquaintance object
            Acquaintance a = new Acquaintance(parts[0], parts[1], Double.parseDouble(parts[2]));

            acqs[0] = a;

            //Add the object to the array

            //(1) create a new Acquaintance array, with one extra element
            Acquaintance[] tmp = new Acquaintance[acqs.length+1];

            //(2) copy all old elements into new
            Acquaintance[] tmp = acqs.clone();

            //(3) assign new Acquaintance object to last element of the array

            //(4) assign new array's address to acqs
            //for loop
        }
```

Comment: This seems like it might be homework?

Comment: Check `ArrayList`'s `ensureCapaciy` method: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.ensureCapacity%28int%29

Comment: Don't remove the question after someone has given the answer. That makes it useless to everyone else.

Answer (score 6):

If your teacher requires a specific method you should probably have listened more closely in class :-)

You can grow an array by one like this:

```
myArray = Arrays.copyOf(myArray,myArray.length+1);
```

but there is no for-loop to be seen. You can do it using older Java methods like this:

```
Object[] tmpArray = new Object[myArray.length+1];
System.arraycopy(myArray,0,tmpArray,0,myArray.length);
myArray = tmpArray;
```

Again, no for-loop required. The only advantage is that it runs with Java 1.5. The only "need" for a for-loop in this question is to do what `System.arraycopy` (which is used by `Arrays.copyOf`) does more efficiently. Like this:

```
Object[] tmpArray = new Object[myArray.length+1];
for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) tmpArray[i]=myArray[i];
myArray = tmpArray;
```

The idea is thus to give you practice in using for-loops, not to actually solve the problem in a good way.

The easiest way to grow an array as you use it is to use some form of `List`, `java.util.ArrayList` for example, let the list handle storing the data, and invoke the List's `toArray()` method when you are finished.

Comment: This is a perfect answer @Simon, thank you! Your first example makes the addition of new objects to an array of objects with an added index value really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(T[] original,int from, int to)
```

method to copy one `array` to diffrent `array`

Comment: the teacher said to use a for loop. How can i incorporate it in such a way that I make a array 1 size larger than before, and then also transfer the old array to new array and than assign the new array to be the old array?

Comment: The `copyOfRange` method can only make arrays smaller or maintain their size. It cannot make arrays larger as the question requires.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore the fact that the requirement to use arrays for this makes no sense whatsoever. What you want to do is assign your initial array a given size, and increase it by a set amount whenever you reach the end of the storage space. Typically, you would increase the underlying storage by a factor of two, whenever you run out of space. Heres some pseudocode:

```
public Acquaintance[] getAcquaitances(final String path) {
    if(path == null) return null;

    int count = 0, initialSize = 16;
    Acquaintance[] temporaryArr = new Acquaintance[initialSize];

    // Open file here

    String line = null;
    while((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
        if(count >= temporaryArr.length) {
            Acquaintance[] switch = temporaryArr;
            temporaryArr = new Acquaintance[switch.length * 2] // increase size by factor of 2
            for(int i = 0; i < switch.length; i++) {
                temporaryArr[i] = switch[i];
            }
         }

         temporaryArr[count] = createAcquantainceFromLine(line);

         ++count;
     }

     Acquaintance[] results = new Acquaintance[count];
     for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         results[i] = temporaryArr[i];
     }

     return results;
}
```

With some slight modifications, the above code should work for you. Study it, embed it, but then totally ignore it and if you ever have a future need for expanding arrays please use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead. Or [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).